# Build Customer View URL on Controller

Tags: magento2, admin, orders, controllers, url

How can I programmatically build this url: http://127.0.0.1/magento2/sales/order/view/order_id/61/?

Im in a custom controller with the current Order object.

Comment: Can you please explain what you exactly need because Magento default gives the same URL whenever you view order details

Comment: Just that, I want to send the view order URL to an external API. So I need to generate it dynamically.

Comment: So you do have Order Id right?

Comment: Yes I have all the Order object. I can do $order->getId();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get website's base URL from this code:

> public $_storeManager;   public function __construct(
> \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
> .....
> ) {
> ...   $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
> } $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_WEB);
>
> $orderUrl = $url.'sales/order/view/order_id/'.$orderId;

You can pass $orderUrl in your external API.